# Child component that gets passed function as props keeps re-render even with React.memo

Tags: reactjs

I use `SideBar` as child component in all 3 parent components.

And SideBar has state of `selectRegion`.

```
  const [selectRegion, setSelectRegion] = useState();
```

And this selectRegion value should be shared between all parent components.

So I make `function` to change state and send it as props in parent, for example component `Users`.

in **Users**

```
 const changeRegion = (passedRegion) => {
    setClickRegion(passedRegion);
  };

  <SideBar changeRegion={changeRegion} />
```

But when I move from parent component to another parent component, for example Users -> Summary, SideBar's selectRegion value is initialized () and then, updated.

And this makes value blinks.

So I don't want SideBar re-rendered unless selectRegion value is changed.

1. I wrap SideBar component with React.memo at last.

> ```
> function SideBar({ changeRegion }) {
> ...
> }
>
> export default React.memo(SideBar);
> ```

But still SideBar keeps rendered when I move from to parent component.

So I wrap `useCallback` with props function in all parent components.

for example, in Users:

```
 const changeRegion = React.useCallback((passedRegion) => {
    setClickRegion(passedRegion);
  }, []);

  <SideBar changeRegion={changeRegion} />
```

However it still blinks.

And I console.log "sidebar" in SideBar component and I check keeps re-rendered and props function `changeRegion` keeps printed.

How can I make SideBar rendered only when selectRegion value is changed?

Comment: Did you try adding passedRegion to dependencies in useCallback?

Comment: Also it kinda seems to me that you don't really need selectRegion state in your sidebar - you can just use prop that is passed from parent to see what user has clicked.

Comment: As an aside, there's a lovely browser extension for react components that will let you see exactly why a component re-rendered. It's helpful to know so you can be sure memo/callback is hitting the right thing. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/react-developer-tools

Comment: @nadjagv - passedRegion comes from SideBar, not in Parent component like Users, so that it says passedRegion is not defined

Comment: Okay than if I understand well - each parent renders SideBar within itself? And sidebar region and rendered parent component should match? If that is the case then the problem with your code is that those are actually different sidebars. I think the best way to solve this is to change architecture a little bit - create a wrapper component that would have region in its state. Based on that state you will render parent component for that region and also pass region to sidebar and use it where needed in sidebar component. This way all your parent components and sidebar will share same state.

Comment: Also you could update state in the wrapper the same way you updated state in parent now - just move the logic from parent to wrapper. In the described approach you could just use passed prop in sidebar, no need for state since sidebar will rerender on region change since it would be a child component to the described wrapper which has region in its state.